# Scrapy always running same command from command prompt

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to learn Scrapy on BashOnUbunty on Windows 10. I created a spider (yelprest) using the genspider command, and then directly created another spider (quotes_spider) by creating the spider file (followed the official tutorial https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html).

The first spider is not yet tested, but I tried to go through the tutorial with second spider, and when I try to run, I'm getting an error which points to the first spider. Also, when I try to run any other scrapy command like version, I'm getting the same error as above. Below is the error:

```
(BashEnv) root > scrapy version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/s/BashEnv/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/mnt/s/BashEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 148, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
  File "/mnt/s/BashEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 243, in __init__
    super(CrawlerProcess, self).__init__(settings)
  File "/mnt/s/BashEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 134, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
  File "/mnt/s/BashEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 330, in _get_spider_loader
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
  File "/mnt/s/BashEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 61, in from_settings
    return cls(settings)
  File "/mnt/s/BashEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._load_all_spiders()
  File "/mnt/s/BashEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 47, in _load_all_spiders
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "/mnt/s/BashEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 71, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/mnt/s/BashEnv/Scrapy/Scrapy/spiders/yelprest.py", line 14
    rules = (
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
(BashEnv) root >
```

I'm not understanding why I am getting the same error for any command I give.

Comment: It looks as a python error. IndentationError means you have a problem in your yelprest.py file. Is your file correctly indented ? Did you mix tabs and spaces ?

Comment: No, the point is the above is the output for the "scrapy version" command - it is completely unrelated. For any command I give, I was getting the above result - every command I give is pointing to the first spider I created with the genspider command. I removed that particular spider from that location, and I am able to run normally. I see from documentation/forums that I should be able to have multiple spiders in the same project. But I am not clear on this particular behavior.

Comment: If you run scrapy command inside a project directory, it will crash if your files contains errors. Even if the command is not related. That's why I think the error is in yelprest.py. 
And yes, you can have multiple spiders in the same project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some error in your `yelprest.py` file (at line 14 or before): it is not valid Python. Fix this error and everything will work. Make sure your file is correctly indented and do not mix spaces and tabs.

**Edit:**

To make sure the error is in this file, just delete it. If everything works without this file, the error must be there!

---

**Update:**

Your question does not state it clearly, but by your comment your question is "why does Scrapy load my spider code for every command?". And the answer is: because Scrapy was made to do it. Some commands can be run only inside a project, like `check` or `crawl`. And some commands may be run anywhere, like `startproject`. But inside a Scrapy project, ANY command will load ALL your code. Scrapy was made this way.

For example, I have a project named `crawler` (I know, very descriptive!):

```
$ cd ~
$ scrapy version
Scrapy 1.4.0
$ cd crawler/
$ scrapy version
2017-10-31 14:47:42 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: crawler)
2017-10-31 14:47:42 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {...}
Scrapy 1.4.0
```

Comment: It points to an indentation error, which I have verified to be correct. But my query was why it was coming to execute this spider, even when I am not pointing to it (ex - I just ran a version command).

Comment: Now it makes sense. Thanks Djunzu!